# Html5 dragging items across and within table cells

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm using Html5 draggable to drag items into different table cells:

http://jsfiddle.net/d1wnk1bg/6/

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="event" id="item1" draggable="true">Item 1</span>
        </td>
        <td><span class="event" id="item2" draggable="true">Item 2</span>
            <span class="event" id="item3" draggable="true">Item 3</span>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.event').on("dragstart", function (event) {
          var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
          dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
        });
    $('table td').on("dragenter dragover drop", function (event) {  
       event.preventDefault();
       if (event.type === 'drop') {
          var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text',$(this).attr('id'));
          de=$('#'+data).detach();
         de.appendTo($(this));  

       };
   });
})
```

The only problem with this approach is that if you drag 'Item 1' into the cell where 'Item 2' and 'Item 3' are, Item 1 gets appended to the end.

How can I modify this so that 'Item 1' can be added before 'Item 2' or between 'Item 2' and 'Item 3'.  I tried going down the rabbit hole of nested draggables but gave up pretty quickly, hoping there's an easier way!

Comment: you could select `item 2 ` or `item 3` in de and then use `before` or `after` functions

Comment: Can you show me how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forked the Fiddle and adjusted the code a bit:

http://jsfiddle.net/gL88q17m/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.event').on("dragstart", function (event) {
        var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
        dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
    });
    $('table td').on("dragenter dragover drop", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.type === 'drop') {
            var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));

            de = $('#' + data).detach();
            if (event.originalEvent.target.tagName === "SPAN") { 
                de.insertBefore($(event.originalEvent.target));
            }
            else {
                 de.appendTo($(this));
            }
        };
    });
})
```

What I did is checking whether the item was dropped directly into the td in which case the dropped element will be inserted after all the other entries or if it was dropped on top of another item in which case the item is inserted just before the item the dropped item was dropped on.

Adding some padding to the td makes it easier to drop an item directly into the td even if there are already 3 items inside.

```
table th, table td {
    width: 200px;
    height:70px;
    padding: 5px;
}
table span {
    display:block;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: fff;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: is there a way to return the span on its original cell if there already a span on the cell to be dropped to?

Answer (score 0):

I have done some changes after reading your comment. Now it is working like a charm. I will recommend reading [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/).

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".event").on("dragstart",function(event){
        var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
        var node = event.target;

        dt.setData('text/html', node.innerHTML);
        dt.setData('text/plain',node.id);
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(".event").on("dragend",function(e){
        event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();
    })

    $(".row>td").on("dragenter dragover dragleave",function(e){
                event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();
    })
    $(".row > td").on("drop",function(event){
       var dragObjId = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
        var data = $("#"+dragObjId);
        var dropTarget = $(event.target).closest("td");
        $(dropTarget).prepend(data);
    });
})
```

Comment: I put your code into the JFiddle I created, but it didn't work, none of the dragging worked well at all.  See http://jsfiddle.net/d1wnk1bg/7/

Comment: check now it will work... I have edited my answer. https://jsfiddle.net/d1wnk1bg/8/

Comment: Thanks, much better, although in column 2, I can't drag item 2 after item 3.  Dragging item 3 in front of item 2 works though

Comment: Ya my code is just a sample so that you can build on top of it. It was just to give you idea how drag drop works. I will recommend not to use jquery for doing this. Use native JS, Its less confusing. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".event").on("dragstart", function(event) {
        var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
        var node = event.target;
        dt.setData('text/html', node.innerHTML);
        dt.setData('text/plain', node.id);
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(".event").on("dragend", function(e) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }) $(".row>td").on("dragenter dragover dragleave", function(e) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }) $(".row > td").on("drop", functiwww.ta3roof.com / on(event) {
        var dragObjId = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
        var data = $("#" + dragObjId);
        var dropTarget = $(event.target).closest("td");
        $(dropTarget).prepend(data);
    });
})
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: I've put this into the jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/d1wnk1bg/11/ and none of the dragging/dropping works at all